# How do I use .pic files as HDRIs in Blender / EasyHDRI

Tags: file-format, hdri

I'm trying to use some HDRIs from [this website](https://www.ihdri.com/hdri-skies-roofed/).
All the files are in .pic format.
The [EasyHDRI Blender plugin](https://codeofart.gumroad.com/l/EasyHDRI) does not read them.
What's the best way to convert or use them?

Comment: This is more a question about the web site rather than Blender. The one I've just downloaded from that site is in .hdr format. Where did you find a .pic format image there?

Comment: Every file I downloaded was a .pic file! My question is precisely about how to use these files in Blender.

Comment: Simple answer is that you can't. That addon doesn't have any facility to convert file formats and is pretty well obsolete nowadays anyway with the arrival of the asset browser in Blender. I'd ty to find out why your files are downloading in the wrong format rather than converting them for use in Blender.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming them as .exr files resolved it